# how does the CPU read from RAM?

Tags: cpu

if I understand correctly, when a CPU communicates with ram over a parallel memory bus, the cpu applies voltage to the address conductors to set the address, then it applies voltage to the control conductor to specify it wants to read, and then the ram applies voltage to the data conductors?
Please tell me whether I've got this right or not. Also, does this mean that this kind of transfer doesn't use a clock signal? Furthermore, is a clock signal in a pc used only for data transfer over serial buses or con it be found in parallel buses too?

Thanks for any answers, no need to go into any depth :)

Answer (score 2):

> if I understand correctly, when a CPU communicates with ram over a parallel memory bus, the cpu applies voltage to the address conductors to set the address, then it applies voltage to the control conductor to specify it wants to read, and then the ram applies voltage to the data conductors? Please tell me whether I've got this right or not.

Yes, that's basically correct.

> Also, does this mean that this kind of transfer doesn't use a clock signal?

It almost has to. Otherwise, how would the RAM know when the address on the bus contained valid data? How would the CPU know when the RAM had put valid data on the bus?

> Furthermore, is a clock signal in a pc used only for data transfer over serial buses or con it be found in parallel buses too?

Parallel buses still need timing. When you output, say, an address, something has to tell the target device when the address is valid. Once that signal is sent, you need to wait until the data is guaranteed valid so the controller can latch it and be assured of getting valid data. This is frequently done with explicit clock signals.